# Equally distributed icons in an Android Progressbar

Tags: android, android-resources, nine-patch

I'm trying something that would sound fairly easy to implement. However, it doesn't respond as expected. I'm using a `Progressbar` to draw a 5 state bar, where the user can click on any of the states to change the behavior of the application. My progressbar uses this drawable (just pay attention to the `background` element).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/statusbar_thin" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="#ffeeeeee"
                    android:startColor="#ffeeeeee" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/statusbar_thin" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This is the `@drawable/statusbar_thin`.

[image]

You may see they just don't look like vertically centered spots, but it doesn't matter. The problem is that, when the image is stretched (it's a 9 patch, as you may expect), the "superior black mark that expands the pixels below it" (I don't know how it's called. Anyone?) expands them *randomly* (By that I mean some parts expand twice more than others).

I'm not sure if there's a trick I didn't use, or it's just Android that uses indistinctly any block, instead of all of them evenly. Any ideas on that?

**EDIT:**

As @sandkasten suggested, I used the draw9patch application. However, as you see, it looks perfectly distributed, but on Nexus 7, it just doesn't work.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

The status bar in black background. As you see, there's a big distance between the first and the second icon, while the selector is inbetween.

[image]

**EDIT 3:** Such an amazing world. I started playing with the top black marks, and, despite they weren't equally distributed at last, it worked.

Comment: Can you add an image how it looks on your nexus 7?

Comment: I'll post it in a couple hours, when I get access to it. Actually, I've seen just to many problems with N7. It also manages pictures coming from camera different than other phones or tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, this should be the solution. Take a look at draw9patch.bat, which shows you a preview of your image and how android strech it. It's deliverd with the android sdk.

[image: New Version]